# How to open sqlite3 installed by Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Ubuntu python2 and python3 both can import sqlite3, but I can not type `sqlite3` in command prompt to open it, it said sqlite3 is not installed, if i want to use it out of python should I install sqlite3 solely using apt-get or I can find it in some directory of python, add it to path and use directly in command line.

I also installed python3.5 on mac, the mac shipped with python2, and I can use sqlite3 in the command line by type `sqlite3`, it is version 3.8.10.2, seems installed by python2, but the python3.5 installed a different version of sqlite3, where can I find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to install anything to use sqlite3 on python.

About sqlite : https://www.sqlite.org/about.html

If you have an experience using database,
you can think sqlite3 is a file like a database include tables.

Because python support sqlite3, you can make a new sqlite3 file.

This example make a new example.db file if not exist only using python.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
# Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
conn.close()
```

Read this doc : https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

But I recommend you to install sqlite to use Command Line Shell For SQLite.

```
$ sqlite3 ex1
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-05-29 12:36:14
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);
sqlite> insert into tbl1 values('hello!',10);
sqlite> insert into tbl1 values('goodbye', 20);
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
hello!|10
goodbye|20
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Robert Moon said, sqlite3 is included in Python since version 2.5, you can use it directly. See his post to have an example.

Sqlite is most a library that manage a SQL database stored in a file. So it is easy to use it in a software or a website, with a language that you can use to make request to your database (stored in a file).

If you want to use sqlite3 outside of a python script, in Ubuntu, you have to install the package

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Then you can run the sqlite terminal

```
sqlite3
```

to make requests, create new databases, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any Cygwin users who find themselves here: run the Cygwin installation .exe...

Choose "Categories", "Database", and then one item says "sqlite3 client to access sqlite3 databases", or words to that effect.